# What I need to install to compile for Platform Toolset v100 using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've just formatted the PC and have Visual Studio 2013 installed. Now, I would like to compile a Visual Studio 2010 C++ solution without convert it and continue targeting v100 platform toolset.

I get the this error:

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets   64  5   TPC30004
```

and project properties I see that of course I miss the needed toolset.

[image: Project properties with Platform Toolset set to Visual Studio 2010 (v100) (not installed)]

I can't change the target because cannot force XP users to install the new C++ 2013 re-distributable so probably I should install Visual Studio 2010 to fix the problem, but if possible I would like to avoid it (small SSD at the moment and not much free space).

Are there other options available?

Comment: I guess that the problem is missing `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V100`. Same at my machine. Tried installing [Multi-Targeting Pack for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.3 (KB2600213)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29052), but it did not help. Still hoping I can avoid installing VS 2010 or having to migrate the app to a newer version of the framework.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to install the Visual Studio 2010 for that. There is no alternative.

You still can install to a different drive, to keep memory footprint on C: as low as possible.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition should also do the job, right?

Comment: Depends on what is need by your project http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Maxence - it became a broken link

Answer (score 1):

There's also the option of installing the Windows SDK 7.1, which comes with the same VS2010 Platform Tools in it and is available for free. Unlike the VS2010 Express edition, it also includes the AMD64 (but not the Itanium) version of the tools.

Comment: Yes, but this does not work on Windows 10, it is not supported.